# How to render WebRTC VideoTrack on SurfaceViewRenderer in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc

Before update `WebRTC` dependencies, I was able to render `WebRTC` `VideoTracks` on `SurfaceViewRenderer` like so:

```
val videoView = findViewById<SurfaceViewRenderer>(R.id.surface_view_renderer)
videoTrack.addRenderer(VideoRenderer(videoView))
```

Since `SurfaceViewRenderer` no longer implements `VideoRenderer.Callbacks` interface, how can I achieve the same behavior above with updated WebRTC version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now `SurfaceViewRenderer` implements `VideoSink` interface and now we can add `VideoSink` interfaces to our `VideoTracks`, so, just replace your current implementation by the following and it will work:

```
val videoView = findViewById<SurfaceViewRenderer>(R.id.surface_view_renderer)
videoTrack.addSink(videoView)
```